# Cannot load imported module named 'Diagnostics.'

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

The build from VS 2013 breaks with the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows
>   Azure Tools\2.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(684,5): error :
>   CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Diagnostics.'

File `ServiceDefinition.csdef`:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="MYWEBPROJECTNAME.Azure"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition"
                   schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
    <WebRole name="MYWEBPROJECTNAME" vmsize="Small">
        <Imports>
            <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
        </Imports>
    </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I've tried to reinstall Azure SDK 2.5 from here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ for VS 2013 and it didn't help.

UPDATE

It breaks at

```
  <ValidateServiceFiles
      ServiceDefinitionFile="@(SourceServiceDefinition)"
      ServiceConfigurationFile="@(SourceServiceConfiguration)">
  </ValidateServiceFiles>
```

The `ValidateServiceFiles` task calls `Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.ImportResolver` and it could not find the 'Diagnostics' module. The task gets its modules from the `ImportedModules` task item array.

UPDATE 2

It looks like there is some mess with VS 2012/2013 installation. On running "VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" (`%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`), msbuild displayed this error. The same on running "Microsoft Azure Command Prompt - v2.5" (`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /K "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\\bin\setenv.cmd"`).

> C:\SOMEPATH\MYWEBPROJECTNAME.Azure.ccproj(72,3): error MSB4019: 
>   The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\
>   Windows Azure Tools\2.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found.
>   Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Removing VS 2012 and repairing VS 2013 didn't help.

Comment: Good luck, fighting the same battle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to remove the  element from my csdef file to get my project to compile. I then followed this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx#BK_Migration

Comment: That article seems to no longer be available... I am seeing this issue with 'Caching'

Answer (score 1):

There is a in the diagnostics approach between the Azure SDK 2.4 and Azure SDK 2.5.  You can read about the changes at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx#BK_Migration.  That said, I had no code impacted by the change, but there ServiceDefinition.csdef had imports to diagnostics.

```
  <Imports>
        <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
        <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
        <Import moduleName="Caching" />
    </Imports>
```

The error was support up in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets.  Since I had no code depending on these module imports I simply commented out the two references to  and things built fine.